# How to send meaningful error to client from a custom authorization policy

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, error-handling, authorization

I have implemented a custom `IAuthorizationPolicy` for a WCF service. It works fine, except than when the authorization fails, the client receives a meaningless error.

If I just `return false` from the `Evaluate` method, the client just receives this:

> **System.ServiceModel.FaultException**: 'The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.  For more information about the error, either turn on IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults (either from ServiceBehaviorAttribute or from the  configuration behavior) on the server in order to send the exception information back to the client, or turn on tracing as per the Microsoft .NET Framework SDK documentation and inspect the server trace logs.'

If I throw a `FaultException<MyCustomErrorDetails>`, the client receives this:

> System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: 'An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:9034/Service1.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.'

Which is even less helpful.

How can I return a meaningful error to the client, such as "authorization failed"?

Comment: Have you considered catching the specific error or errors based on exception types and formatting a return string that is more user friendly?

Comment: When I say "the client", I mean the client app, not the user. The exceptions I showed in the question are what the client app receives; I can't do anything with them, they could mean anything.

Comment: So you're saying that you can't alter your public web method to return a custom error description to the client calling such?

Comment: @codemaker it's not the public service method that throws, it's the authorization policy

Answer (score 2):

Enabling detailed error messages in a WCF service can be done through behavior configuration:

```xml
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>      
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
```

Typically you would create a type which holds the fault information, for example:

```csharp
[DataContract]
public class SecurityFault
{
    private string operation;
    private string problemType;

    [DataMember]
    public string Operation
    {
        get { return operation; }
        set { operation = value; }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string ProblemType
    {
        get { return problemType; }
        set { problemType = value; }
    }
}
```

In the service contract you would need to decorate the operations with the fault contract, like so:

```csharp
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [FaultContract(typeof(SecurityFault))]
    int Divide(int number1, int number2);
}
```

In this case you would throw the exception in the authorization policy, for example:

```csharp
public class AuthorizationAlwaysFails : IAuthorizationPolicy
{
    public ClaimSet Issuer => throw new NotImplementedException();

    public string Id => Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

    public bool Evaluate(EvaluationContext evaluationContext, ref object state)
    {
        var sf = new SecurityFault();
        sf.Operation = "Authorization";
        sf.ProblemType = "Authorization failed";
        throw new FaultException<SecurityFault>(sf);
    }
}
```

Client applications can then catch the exception as follows:

```csharp
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var wcfClient = new MyService.ServiceClient();

        try
        {
            var result = wcfClient.Divide(10, 5);
            Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
        catch (FaultException<SecurityFault> securityFault)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(securityFault.Detail.Operation);
            Console.WriteLine(securityFault.Detail.ProblemType);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm aware of `includeExceptionDetailInFaults`, but it's a debug setting, it's not supposed to be enabled in production. Is there no way to return a specific error message without enabling this?

Comment: With the setting disabled the fault contract would still work for exceptions thrown after authorization. What you could do is authorize the client, but in a specific user role (i.e. Guest). This allows you to decorate service operations with a custom attribute which would check the role and still throw the security fault when higher permissions are needed.